# StripeJS createToken requires a secret key instead of publishable key

Tags: stripe-payments

Assume the following code:

```
const stripe = window.Stripe('pk_xxx', { stripeAccount: 'acct_xxx' });
const elements = stripe.elements();
const card = elements.create('card');

stripe.createToken(card);
```

It succeeds in 3 of the 4 possible setups (test environment making LIVE stripe calls, test environment making TEST stripe calls, live environment making LIVE stripe calls) but not when in a live environment making TEST stripe calls.

It fails with a 403 error and the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "secret_key_required",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/secret-key-required",
    "message": "This API call cannot be made with a publishable API key. Please use a secret API key. You can find a list of your API keys at https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys.",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

How can a JS call require the secret key? Everyone would see it.

Here is the HTTP request:

```
card[number]: 4242424242424242
card[cvc]: 242
card[exp_month]: 04
card[exp_year]: 24
card[address_zip]: 42424
guid: 282d554c-4271-4730-9df4-ad142b19a812
muid: 722e4d63-4df0-40db-8d60-100f841d1718
sid: d5f44fce-9835-497b-a4dd-766894b4c23a
payment_user_agent: stripe.js/3b5fc4c8; stripe-js-v3/3b5fc4c8
referrer: https://app.myowndomain.com/
key: pk_test_xxx (also tried the pk_live_xxx - no difference)
_stripe_account: acct_xxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the requested scope using Stripe Connect. It was set to "read_only", while I needed "read_write".

Stripe support acknowledged the fact that the current error message is not intuitive at all, and have passed the information to the engineering team so it is less confusing for developers.

Answer (score 0):

Token creation would never require a Secret API key. This would be a real security issue and that's why Stripe has a pair of keys: the Secret key for your server-side code and the Publishable key for your client-side code.

The code you shared would always work with a publishable key and creating a token would never fail with that error. The Publishable key is also what is documented: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js

It is tricky to say what is causing this in your example but it has to be something unrelated to that line of code. Something else in the code would be triggered after the token creation and that other part must be misconfigured and have your Publishable key server-side. I would recommend following up with Stripe's support team on this as they can investigate your account directly: https://support.stripe.com/email